# Which polls count towards DNC debate requirements (especially the fall debates)?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, democratic-primary, debate, polling

There are polls released almost daily pertaining to the Democratic nomination.  In order to attend the September 12–13 round of debates, candidates need to get donations from 130,000 unique donors and attain at least 2% in 4 polls (national or early state) from some list of approved pollsters. All polls must be after June 28th.

I like to look up the results of the polls as they are released (realclearpolitics) but I have no idea which pollsters are approved and (if applicable) which of their polls count. I have attempted to google this but keep finding news articles explaining the information above instead of answering this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official source](https://democrats.org/press/third-debate/), polls from an "approved organization" currently include the following:

- Associated Press
- ABC News
- CBS News
- CNN
- Des Moines Register
- Fox News
- Monmouth University
- NBC News
- New York Times
- National Public Radio (NPR)
- Quinnipiac University
- University of New Hampshire
- Wall Street Journal
- USA Today
- Washington Post
- Winthrop University.

However, the candidates' four qualifying polls must be conducted by different organizations so they can't just get one pollster to give them 4 good polling outcomes. Also, the DNC reserves the right to add a "Nevada-specific poll sponsor" to the list so we will have to wait to see what that means.

Comment: The University of New Hampshire and Des Moines Register are examples of New Hampshire and Iowa specific poll sponsors.  Presumably they are looking for a Nevada equivalent.  Those are the first three primary/caucus states, so they have special significance.  South Carolina would be the fourth.  A number of states tie for fifth.

Comment: Thank you again for this.  Turns out that the site you linked in 100% percent what I was looking for but had been unsuccessful in finding.